# How can I "dim" the rest of the web page when displaying a notification DIV?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my web app, I'm displaying a "notification" DIV.

I would like to "dim" the rest of the page, so that the notification DIV stands out even more when displayed.

Is there a reasonably easy way of doing so?

This question is only concerned with visual effects, NOT the functionality of the rest of the page.

Here is an example of the functionality I found elsewhere on the web (though in this case the dialog was a pop-up JS one, and not a DIV):

[image]

Comment: the phrase you are looking for is "lightbox"

Comment: You superimpose a transluscent div over the entire viewport to "dim" everything else, then superimpose a "solid" div on top of that to display your message.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use this CSS:

```
#overlay{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  opacity:0.6; /* see below for cross-browser opacity */
}
```

### [Working Example](http://jsbin.com/ezidpic/3)

In the example above, this bit creates overlay:

```
// main overlay container
$('<div id="__msg_overlay">').css({
      "width" : "100%"
    , "height" : "100%"
    , "background" : "#000"
    , "position" : "fixed"
    , "top" : "0"
    , "left" : "0"
    , "zIndex" : "50"
    , "MsFilter" : "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)"
    , "filter" : "alpha(opacity=60)"
    , "MozOpacity" : 0.6
    , "KhtmlOpacity" : 0.6
    , "opacity" : 0.6

}).appendTo(document.body);
```

Dialog box is then added on that overlay element with higher `z-index`.

Comment: Position Fixed is not cross-browser, but you can make a div the size of the entire page being displayed as a fallback to the above, same logic.

Comment: @MyStream: I know, who cares about IE6 these days :)

Comment: The sooner we don't the better! hear hear :) but, just for those still doing contracts/work for local government, council or outdated office environments, it's worth pointing out an alternative should they stumble.  Hopefully IE6 will be gone soon.

Comment: @MyStream: Agreed, if IE6 is the concern, one would use `absolute` then.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fairly [simple lightbox example](https://web.archive.org/web/20140213034137/http://thinkclay.com/news/jquery-lightbox-modal-plugin) that should demonstrate the basics. It uses jQuery, but could easily be unrolled into vanilla javascript if need be.

The basic concept is you have a div that takes up the entire display area (`.overlay`) that is a semitransparent black and then another div that is positioned *in front* of that (`.modal`) which would be the content of your dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use a jquery plugin or already existing lightbox library, like in the previous answer or  http://defunkt.io/facebox/ or http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

If your still want to use the CSS.. generally it looks like

```
 #overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The "opacity" rule is responsible for the "dimness", the other rules are responsible for making the opacity is applied to an element the covers the whole page.