# Disabling the background from css/js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a signature pad on my web interface, I want to disable everything apart from that signature pad once a user clicks on it. I want the signature pad to be there by disabling everything else, by disabling I mean making it light black, as in modal.

Here is the code.

```
 <body>
    <!-- Some Code -->

    <div class="sig sigWrapper current" style="display: block;">
    <div class="typed" style="display: none; ">
    </div> 
    <canvas class="pad" width="310" height="75" id="signature_pad">
    </canvas>
    <input type="hidden" name="output" class="output validate[required]" value="">
    </div>
    <!-- Some more Code -->
 </body>
```

Comment: Where is your code? Post some code first.

Comment: Put this code into your post not in comment

Comment: Please add your CSS code of the particular section your talking about.

Comment: The css and javascript is from the signaturepad library. I want to create a new css, which also gets enabled once i click on this signature pad. that css/js should disable the whole background except this particular signature pad.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455556/how-can-i-dim-the-rest-of-the-web-page-when-displaying-a-notification-div