# How to revert the vague background using javascript (hidden using jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used this way to hide the screen behind a div ([How can I "dim" the rest of the web page when displaying a notification DIV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455556/how-can-i-dim-the-rest-of-the-web-page-when-displaying-a-notification-div)) , I want to ask how to revert the changes in a javascript function, I will call that function on clicking the cross on the div displayed

Here is my code:

```
function addalbum()
{
    $('<div id="__msg_wrapper">').css({
      "width" : "100%"
    , "height" : "100%"
    , "background" : "#000"
    , "position" : "fixed"
    , "top" : "0"
    , "left" : "0"
    , "zIndex" : "50"
    , "MsFilter" : "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)"
    , "filter" : "alpha(opacity=60)"
    , "MozOpacity" : 0.6
    , "KhtmlOpacity" : 0.6
    , "opacity" : 0.6
    }).appendTo(document.body);

    document.getElementById("album_name").style.display = "block";
}
```

This code fade the "wrapper" div and show the div with id "album_name", but how to revert the "wrapper" div to its original state

Comment: Can you provide what you've tried?

Comment: I have updated my question, have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

You can just use .show() and .hide() on the overlay div.

You can also fade it to make for a nicer switch.